# WC 3.x Get categories from variable product of the cart

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get the categories of each product in the cart, then I have this code:

```
<?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) :
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    $array_cat[] = $_product->get_category_ids();
endforeach;
?>
```

This code works fine with simple product but with variable product it show empty.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) :
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    $array_cat1 = $_product->get_category_ids();
    $array_cat2 = wc_get_product_terms( $_product->get_id(),'product_cat' );
    $array_cat3 = wp_get_post_terms( $_product->get_id(),'product_cat' );
    $array_cat4 = get_the_terms( $_product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    $array_cat5 = get_the_term_list($_product->get_id(), 'product_cat');
endforeach;
?>
```

but in all these cases, it show empty.

Please could you help with it?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it.

In a variable product `$_product->get_id()` is not of ID the product else is the ID only of these variation at cart.

Then, in these loop can found the id of product in the variable  `$cart_item['product_id']`

We can use it:

```
$the_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
$array_cat = $the_product->get_category_ids();
```

Regards